# How to insert data to existing column where id = ...?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created table in my database with scores (10 records). They are now empty but I want them to be updated after user make some quiz.

Now my function looks like this :

```
public boolean insertScore(float score, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("Score", score);
        long result = db.insert("Scores" , null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but I would like to put the data to row with id equals the id argument. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to update the existing values of the column `score` and not insert new rows:

```
public boolean updateScore(float score, int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Score", score);
    long result = db.update("Scores", contentValues, "id = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();
    return result > 0;
}
```

The method `update()` returns the number of the rows affected, so your method `updateScore()` will return `true` if the row with specified `id` was updated.